# How to allow access to memory in a kernel module?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

Suppose I have a memory-mapped peripheral which can be read from or written to at some address, say 0x43C00000. I want to be able to read from that same memory location in my Linux OS in order to communicate with that peripheral. Since the address in question would be a physical address, I should be able to write a kernel module that can read from that address location.

In the kernel, if I have something like

```
#define BASE_ADDR   0x43C00000
#define OFFSET      4

    int     * mem_addr;

    mem_addr = BASEADDR + OFFSET;
```

That, I think, should give me the pointer to the second writing block of the peripheral, at 0x43C00004. Printing

```
    printk(KERN_INFO "%p\n", mem_addr)
```

seems to tell me this is right.

Now if I try to do something like

```
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n", *mem_addr);
```

I would have thought that that should therefore read the data that is being written to memory by my peripheral, accomplishing what I was trying to do. But if I try putting a statement like this into a module, Linux kills it. Looking at my /var/log/messages I see this:

```
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Modules linked in; TEST_MOD(0+) ...
```

followed by a bunch of information about register states. So I'm apparently not allowed to just read memory like that. Is there some way to grant access to a kernel module to read memory?

Comment: What language is this, in which you use an `=` in a `#define` directive?

Comment: My mistake, I copied wrong.

Comment: Why is this "off-topic" it's totally on topic, and is a completely valid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a kernel virtual address mapping for the location e.g.

> `mem_addr = ioremap_nocache(BASEADDR + OFFSET, SIZE);`

(you appear to have asked the same question twice - see [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296983/36176)).